# How can I read byte() geometry into array of points using VBScript?

Tags: .net, vbscript, windows-scripting, ogr, wkb

I have a binary file "geo.bin" that represents some geometry (OGR WKB I think). The binary file has a list of points that make up a polygon. I'd like to read the binary data and create an array of points in my VBScript script.

Are there solutions that already exist I can leverage? Perhaps a .NET class like DbGeometry? If so how would I instantiate such a class? I have tried the following but get an error "ActiveX component can't create object: 'GetObject'":

```
Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim logfile
Set logfile = fso.CreateTextFile("A:\Atoll\geotest.log")

'read binary geometry into byte array
Dim stream, bytes
Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
stream.Open
stream.Type = 1
stream.LoadFromFile("A:\Atoll\geo.bin")
bytes = stream.Read
stream.Close

Dim dbgeo: Set dbgeo = GetObject("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Data.Entity.dll", "DbGeometry")
logfile.Write(TypeName(dbgeo) & vbCrLf)

Dim poly: Set poly = dbgeo.FromBinary(bytes)
```

I've also tried using:

```
Dim dbgeo: Set dbgeo = CreateObject("System.Data.Spatial.DbGeometry")
```

But get a similar error.

Comment: VBScript cannot use .Net classes unless they expose a COM interface. Use PowerShell instead.

Comment: Unfortunately in this instance I'm forced to use VBScript. I will look into executing a Powershell script from VBScript. That should work so long as I can get the PS script to return data to my VBScript script.

Comment: You might be able to interpret the data with VBScript as well, but AFAIK there's nothing ready-made for VBScript, so you'll have to do implement it yourself. You need to provide information about the source and destination formats if you want us to help with that.